# Mongo shell does not show collections (command show collections) when insert through Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, npm, database

[This is my project `url-shortener` directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bAJm.png)

I have a Node JS app that involves using MongoDB. It works fine, as I tried inserting, finding, and printing data from MongoDB to the console in the Node JS file, server.js. However, if I open a Mongo Shell and type `show collections`, it would show nothing.

Here is how I establish MongoDB connection:

`mongod --dbpath ...path-to-project/url-shortener/data`,

Here is the url I use to connect in my `server.js` file:

`var dbUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/url-shortener";`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe you should first pick a db

```
> show dbs
db1
db2
```

Then after using a datbase

```
>use db1
```

You will see its collections:

```
>show collections
collection1
collection2
```

Finally use it:

```
> db.collection1.find()
```

Comment: Are you sure `show db` is a valid command? I get `[thread1] Error: don't know how to show [db] :`

Comment: Got it. Thank you. It drove me crazy for the past hour

Comment: Got it! I was doing `use collection_name`